# How to obtain airspeed data

Tags: sensors, sensor-fusion

I want to measure the airspeed on a flying vehicle and get the data with a microcontroller. Note that, there will not be any control mechanism on the flying object, it will be flying mechanicaly/passively, I mean no flight controller or something like that will be present.

However, I could not understand whether there is a sensor to measure the airspeed directly or is airspeed something you analyze by using other datas(temperature, pressure etc.)

I saw there are sensors which are sold as "airspeed sensor" however it is not so common that I cannot find examples in which the incoming data is shown.

Anybody ever experienced with this issue may lighten me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: air speed is fairly difficult to obtain without the use of a sensor that is attached to the aircraft .... you would have to determine wind speed and direction, aircraft ground speed and direction, and then use those two vectors to calculate the aircraft airspeed

Comment: please do not post at multiple sites ... https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/70646/how-to-get-air-speed-which-sensor-to-use

Comment: Are you looking for something like the [Pixhawk Digital Airspeed Sensor](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/pixhawk-digital-airspeed-sensor-w-pitot-tube.html)?

Comment: @sempaiscube "This sensor must be used in conjuction with the Pixhawk PX4 autopilot system." This is the problem, I will not use apm or pixhawk, however all these sensors say that they are produced to be used with either pixhawk or apm. Can I get data out of them without not connecting it to a pixhawk?

Comment: Which microcontroller are you using?

Comment: @HighVoltage actually, the project has been suspended which I was working on. So, thanks but no need anymore.